# .Net MAUI Web Authenticator Hangs

Tags: android, .net, authentication, maui

[Following the official guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/communication/authentication?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=android), I've implemented the WebAuthenticator in my .NET Maui Android App to handle SSO auth with Facebook.

It's a fairly straightforward implementation, I've added the .Net core backend on a website with the mobile auth endpoint implemented as directed, and that appears to be working.

However when the WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync method is calling the API, it's hanging:

```
private void OnFacebookClicked(object sending, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        WebAuthenticatorResult authResult = WebAuthenticator.Default.AuthenticateAsync(
            new Uri("https://testwebsite.azurewebsites.net/mobileauth/Facebook"),
            new Uri("xamarinessentials://")).Result;

        string accessToken = authResult?.AccessToken;

    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        // User stopped auth
    }
}
```

I don't get any kind of response back - no timeout, no exception, nothing just a straight hang.

Any advice?

Comment: That is "deadlock". Its why its best to never use `.Wait` or `.Result` on Async calls. For a click-handler, can do `private async void OnFacebookClicked`, then use `await` inside it. If need more help, search for the many discussions of `async/await`.

Comment: thanks - using an awaiter indeed did the trick !